# Jquery - Carousel Previous button

Tags: jquery

The next button is fine, but for the previous button, it jump not smoothly.Thanks in advance everyone for helping me.Why my previous doesn't work as my next button?

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide">
        <ul class="wrap-all">
            <li>
                <img src="index.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="index1.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="index2.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="index3.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="arrow">
            <a href="#" class="pre">Previous</a>    
            <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide{
     width: 550px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 130px;
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
 }
 ul.wrap-all{
     list-style: none;
     position: relative;
 }
 ul.wrap-all li{
     float: left;
     width: 275px;

 }
 .next{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     right: 0;
     color: white;
 }
 .pre{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 0;
     color: white;
 }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var itemWidth = $('.wrap-all li').outerWidth(true);
    var imageLength = $('.wrap-all li').length;
    var totalImage = itemWidth * imageLength;
    $('.wrap-all').css('width', totalImage);      
        $('.next').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.wrap-all:not(:animated)').animate({
             left: -itemWidth
            },200,
            function(){
                $('.wrap-all li:last').after($('.wrap-all li:first'));
                $('.wrap-all').css({'left': 0});
            });
        });
        $('.pre').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           $('.wrap-all:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : +itemWidth}, 200,function(){
            $('.wrap-all li:first').before($('.wrap-all li:last'));
            $('.wrap-all').css({'left' : 0});
            });
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with why it doesn't work so well is because the animation doesn't actually have a previous image in the slide before running.  so after the animation slides left to right it then adds the first image.

A way to fix this is by wrapping the the images in another div tag that hides the first image and displays the next 2, that way the animation appears smooth when going left to right since the image added will still be hidden.

Here's some code I used to make the animation look more fluent.  (I didn't modify the JS you used so i won't include it here)

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide">
<div class="viewer">
    <ul class="wrap-all">
        <li>
            <img src="http://ckinknoazoro.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/random.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://ts3.mm.bing.net/th?id=H.4936237002655974&pid=1.7" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/5700000/Random-random-5719756-1280-800.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/9400000/Random-random-9449476-1680-1050.jpg" alt="" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="arrow">
    <a href="#" class="pre">Previous</a>    
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 img {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
}

.viewer{

    width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left: -200px; 
}
.slide{
     width: 600px;
     height: 130px;
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     margin:auto;
 }
 ul.wrap-all{
     list-style: none;
     position: relative;
 }
 ul.wrap-all li{
     float: left;
     width: 275px;

 }
 .next{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     right: 0;
     color: black
 }
 .pre{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 0;
     color: black
 }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks you for replied, I will fix it, then reply you back as soon as possible.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think so

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
var itemWidth = $('.wrap-all li').outerWidth(true);
var imageLength = $('.wrap-all li').length;
$('.wrap-all').css({'left': -itemWidth});
var totalImage = itemWidth * imageLength;
$('.wrap-all').css('width', totalImage);      
    $('.next').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.wrap-all:not(:animated)').animate({
         left: (-2 * itemWidth)
        },200,
        function(){
            $('.wrap-all li:last').after($('.wrap-all li:first'));
            $('.wrap-all').css({'left': -itemWidth});
        });
    });
    $('.pre').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       $('.wrap-all:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : 0}, 200,function(){
        $('.wrap-all li:first').before($('.wrap-all li:last'));
        $('.wrap-all').css({'left' : -itemWidth});
        });
    });
 });
```